# Access the 'current' scope from a 'root' controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one controller I think of as my 'root' controller, it is the one declared with an `ng-controller` attribute, then a few other controllers that are instantiated dynamically via a `$routeProvider`. I want to declare a function that will be available via an `ng-click` attribute in scope of any of the dynamic/child controllers.

I can declare the function on my root controller, e.g.

```
$scope.announce = function () {
    alert($scope.specificName);
}
```

then I see it on all of the scopes for all the 'child' controllers, but the `$scope` used in this function is local to the root controller, not the currently active scope/controller. How can I access the active, child scope in this function?

Comment: Can you add some use case of your function ? (Are you using it with ng-click ? inside an other function ? etc...)

Comment: You can always use factories and event emitter to communicate between controllers. I have a similar thing with a menu controller which gets updated every time some logs in or out, or adds something to a shopping basket.... I don't know if this is along the same lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just pass the child scope as parameter:

In your "root" controller:

```
$scope.announce = function (childScope) {
    alert(childScope.specificName);
};
```

In your "child" controller:

```
$scope.announce($scope);
```

Or, since you need to call the function from a `ng-click`:
In your "child" controller:

```
$scope.callAnnounce = function(){
    $scope.announce($scope)
};
```

The advantage here is that you can have the same code in your child controllers, and only have to modify the function in your root controller, should you have to edit the functionality.

Comment: That means I have to declare a function that calls `announce` in each child controller, something I'd prefer to avoid, but it's not a train smash if I have to.

Comment: Eh, no you don't. You can declare the announce function in the root controller. You can then simply use it in your child controllers

Comment: I want to call `announce` from an `ng-click` function, and I think that function will have to pass `$scope` to `announce`, and it seems to me that function will have to exist in each controller.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yea, in that case you will need to add a function to each child controller. Luckily they all can be something like `$scope.ann = function(){ $scope.announce($scope) }`

Answer (score 5):

I've got something working in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SIV7NN3cyYaOO0TxxcO8?p=preview) that cover some usecases.

The function will take a parameter. This parameter will have the same name in each scope.

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="announce(specificName)">announce in main</button>
    <div ng-controller="subCtrl">
      <button ng-click="announce(specificName)">announce in sub</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You main controller look like that :

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, ItemService){

    $scope.specificName = "I'm main !";
    $scope.announce = function(specificName){
      alert(specificName);
    }
    
});
```

And just override the "specificName" var in the sub controller :

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('subCtrl', function($scope, ItemService){

    $scope.specificName = "I'm a sub !";
    
});
```

To call the function in pure JS you can do this in each controller :

```
$scope.announce($scope.specificName);
```

**EDIT :**

I just realized that there is an other solution that could meet your need. You could use a factory or a service to share the function.

How the service could look :

```
myApp.service("AnnounceService",
    function(){
        var service = {};

        service.announce = function(toAnnounce){
              alert(toAnnounce);
        }

        return service;
    }
);
```

How your controller will look like :

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('subCtrl', function($scope, AnnounceService){

    $scope.announce = AnnounceService.announce;
    $scope.specificName = "I'm a sub !";

    //Equivalent
    $scope.announce($scope.specificName);
    AnnounceService.announce($scope.specificName);
    
});
```

This is the same thing as you need to declare the specificName in each controller and pass it to the function. But the function will be usable in any part of your application. You just need to inject the service and

**Details :**

Finally the abstract part in not the function but the name of your var in each controller. A kind of conventional naming.

If this var is state related you can add it in the state definition. (If that's the case i could try to give you an example.)

I also don't recommend at all to give a complete $scope to an other one. That's not a good practice in angular.

Hoping this solved your problem, or give enough clues.

Feel free to ask for more specific thing i'll edit the answer to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for a very helpful answer, but Cerbrus did solve my problem first.

Comment: @ProfK True, but keep it mind that you shoudn't give a complete scope into a function. This isn't a good practice.